# Formatting a string to microseconds

Tags: python, math, formatting

Looking to format a output to show a very small number..

```
a= 6500
b= 3600
c=.000900
d= int((b/a)-c)
print d
```

Answer comes out to be zero, but looking for the .###### numbers after the .

sorry try this

Comment: When I print `d`, I get `-0.0009` (python2.x) -- It'll be different on python3.x because of true-division (which I think you probably want here).

Comment: Your edit added `int`, but you say that you want the fractional part of the calculation. This seems inconsistent, since `int` will explicitly throw away those parts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you got bitten by integer division in python 2.x.

```
>>> a= 6500
>>> b= 3600
>>> c=.000900
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> print b/a - c
0.552946153846
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be two issues with your calculation:

If you're using Python 2, division using `/` between two integers will always be an integer also. This will discard the fractional part of the calculation, which can be unexpected. One fix for this is to force one of the values to be a `float` value (e.g. `float(b)/a`). An alternative is to put at the top of your file `from __future__ import division`, which tells Python to use the Python 3 semantics for division (you'll only get an integer from integer division if the result is an exact integer).

The second issue seems to be about formatting a floating point value. First you seem to want only the fractional part of the value (not the integer part). Usually the best option is to simply subtract the integer part of the value:

```
d = someFloatingPointValue()
d_frac = d - int(d)
```

Next, to get a string to output (where you want several decimal places, but not a huge number of them), you probably want to explore Python's string formatting operations:

```
d = someFloatingPointValue()
d_to4decimalPlaces = "{:.4f}".format(d)
```